# Trouble fine tuning Huggingface GPT-2 on Colab -- Assertion error

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

I wish to fine tune Huggingface's GPT-2 transformer model on my own text data. I want to do this on a Google Colab notebook. However, I have two problems. The first is that it doesn't seem to work.

I install the various bits and pieces via the Colab:

```
!git clone https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
%cd transformers
!pip install .
!pip install -r ./examples/requirements.txt
```

[Following the example](https://huggingface.co/transformers/examples.html), I upload the suggested WikiText sample data to the for training and run the suggested CLI commands in the notebook.

```
!export TRAIN_FILE=wiki.train.raw
!export TEST_FILE=wiki.test.raw

!python run_lm_finetuning.py \
    --output_dir=output \
    --model_type=gpt2 \
    --model_name_or_path=gpt2 \
    --do_train \
    --train_data_file=$TRAIN_FILE \
    --do_eval \
    --eval_data_file=$TEST_FILE
```

This chugs along for a bit, but then I get an assertion error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_lm_finetuning.py", line 790, in <module>
    main()
  File "run_lm_finetuning.py", line 735, in main
    train_dataset = load_and_cache_examples(args, tokenizer, evaluate=False)
  File "run_lm_finetuning.py", line 149, in load_and_cache_examples
    return TextDataset(tokenizer, args, file_path=file_path, block_size=args.block_size)
  File "run_lm_finetuning.py", line 88, in __init__
    assert os.path.isfile(file_path)
AssertionError
```

I think this is to do with my training data? Note that both files in the same folder as the lm_finetuning.py script, so I'm not sure what the os.path issue might be.

```
benchmarks.py     run_generation.py   summarization
contrib       run_glue.py         test_examples.py
distillation      run_lm_finetuning.py    tests_samples
hans          run_multiple_choice.py  utils_multiple_choice.py
mm-imdb       run_ner.py          utils_ner.py
pplm          run_squad.py        wiki.test.raw
README.md     run_tf_glue.py      wiki.test.tokens
requirements.txt  run_tf_ner.py       wiki.train.raw
run_bertology.py  run_xnli.py         wiki.train.tokens
```

My second problem is that, even if fine tuning did work, I don't know how to duplicate the results with my own text data. I can't open the WikiText raw files, so I have no idea what format they're in. Are the ordinary plain text? Are they tokenized in some way? If anyone can enlighten me on this it would would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else comes looking for the solution, the answer is that environment variables in bash need to be specified with `%` and not `!` in a google colab. So the script should be:

```
%env TRAIN_FILE=/content/wiki.train.raw
%env TEST_FILE=/content/wiki.test.raw

!python /content/transformers/examples/run_lm_finetuning.py \
    --output_dir=output \
    --model_type=gpt2 \
    --model_name_or_path=gpt2 \
    --do_train \
    --train_data_file=/content/wiki.train.raw \
    --do_eval \
    --eval_data_file=/content/wiki.test.raw
```

Note too that it became easier to use absolute over relative filepaths. Hat-tip to cronoik on the hugginface GitHub repo for pointing all of this out.